# How to Add a SoundCloud Shortcode blow post excerpt?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog with posts displayed at the frontpage, The posts are displayed with its excerpt and read more button below it.

I want to add my Soundcloud files in between post excerpt and “read more” button for each post, So How can I achieve that?

[image: http://prntscr.com/dvvl8c]

this is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-embed-soundcloud-in-your-wordpress-posts-by-using-oembed/

Place shortcode under your excerpt content.